# Looking for some special functions

Tags: special-functions

I'm looking for some continuous functions $\{f_i(x,t)\}$, here $x=(x_1,x_2..., x_n)$, such that:

- $f_i(x,t):R^n\times [0, +\infty)\rightarrow R  ~~\text{is continuous for each}~~i $
- $f_i(x,0)=x_i$
- $\Sigma_1^n f_i^2(x,t)\rightarrow \infty ~~\text{as}~~\|(x,t)\|^2=\Sigma_1^n x_i+t^2  \rightarrow \infty$

If such functions exist, could you please show me some examples, thanks.

Comment: why not just $f_i(x,t)=x_i$?

Comment: @ Carlo Beenakker， because in this case, the third condition doesn't satisfy when $x=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want squares on $x_i$ in the expression for the norm: $\|(x,t)\|^2=x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2+t^2$.

Then I believe there are no such functions for topological reasons. Consider the restriction of $f=(f_1,\dots,f_n)$ to a half-sphere
$$X=\{(x,t);\,x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2+t^2=C,\,t\geq 0\}.$$
Suppose that $f\neq 0$ on $X$. Then, $f/|f|$ would be a continuous map from $X$ to the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$ in $\mathbb R^n$. Moreover, the restriction to the boundary $t=0$ is $f(x,0)=x/|x|$, that is, it is the identity under the natural identification $\partial X\approx S^{n-1}$. My understanding of algebraic topology is near zero, but I believe it follows from homotopy theory that no such map exists. So $f$ has a zero on $X$ for any $C>0$, which contradicts your last assumption.

Comment: anyway, thank you.